# Best practice using RX - return an Observable or accept an Observer?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Using Reactive Extensions, I can think of a number of ways to model an operation that has side effects / IO - say subscribe to messages from a chat room. I could either accept parameters (say the chat room), and an Observer, returning a Disposable, i.e.

```
Disposable SubscribeTo(string chatRoom, Observer<ChatMessage> observer)
```

or return an Observable given the parameters, i.e.

```
Observable<ChatMessage> GetObservableFor(string chatRoom)
```

When returning an Observable, I additionally have the choice between making it "hot" or "cold", i.e. performing the actual subscription either when my method is called or when the observable is subscribed to. In addition, I could make the observable multiplexed or not, i.e. share the same underlying subscription when there are more than one subscribers to the Observable, or initiate a new request each time it is subscribed to.

Is there a best practice approach to this using RX for operations that subscribe to an external source of events with parameters?

Answer (score 8):

Returning an **I**Observable is much better, as you are then able to compose the returned IObservable with other operators.  Trying to put things into a custom SubscribeTo method seems like a bad idea to me, because there's nothing composable about SubscribeTo, so you are kind of painting yourself into a corner.  If you return IObservable then you can decide later if you want to Publish/Defer, etc..., whenever you want, just by using the existing operators for IO.  If you do it inside SubscribeTo, it's decided, and everything must partake in the consequences.  The behavior would be wrapped up in SubscribeTo, which defeats the purpose of IO ... to be explicit about any side effects.

Comment: Being explicit about side effects it the reason why I would use the explicit "subscribe to" form. You know as a caller that invoking that function will make things happen, and once for each call, it is apparent from the contract that this must be the case.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the other two answers. I would like to further add some clarifications:

1. If your observable sequence is Hot, it is almost certainly shared. So it sounds like you may have some confusion there as you talk about Hot and Shared as different things.
2. I think it is fine for a *subscription* to have side-effects. In Functional Programming, most discussions about avoiding side-effects are with regards to the *operators* in the pipeline, not the construction of the pipeline. i.e. don't create side effects in your `Where`/`Select`/`Take` etc... operators. To do so creates a jarring experience and leads to unpredictable outcomes. This prevents safe composition, which is a corner stone of FP.
3. Is is totally fine to pass parameters to a method that returns an observable sequence! Your sample is a great example of when to do so. Other examples include subscribing to a channel, endpoint, session, timer etc...
4. Avoid the usage of custom implementations of `IObservable<T>`. It is just a no-no. I have been using Rx for well over 3 years now and there is just no need for it. Even using the Subject implementations is a rare occurrence. As Brad said, look to [Observable.Create](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#ObservableCreate) for creating sequences.*

To summarize, I suggest that you end up with an interface that looks like this:

```
IObservable<ChatMessage> MessagesFor(string chatRoom)
```

RE your question of sharing observable sequences, is very much something you need to decide based on your own requirements and architecture. Sometimes you may find that the underlying transport layers will do this for you, so there is no need to you to code it. Other times you may find that sharing a subscription means that the second+ subscribers may miss out on messages that only occur on subscription (e.g. State-Of-World). You could over come this by using a ReplaySubject as your MultiCaster. This raises other issues; are you prepared to take a possibly unbounded cost of storing ChatMessages?

*Disclosure: The link is to my own website

Answer (score 3):

`IObservable` has a method called Subscribe with a ton of overloads. There is no reason for you to write a custom SubscribeTo method. It's an anti pattern.

```
var o = ChatRoom.ObservableFor("alt.buddha.short.fat.guy").Publish().RefCount()
```

to make a multicast that goes hot on the first subscription then cold when the last subscription is dropped.

Comment: On the other hand, it's very easy to make an Observable from something accepting an Observer and returning a Disposable, and it would make it more obvious where the side effect occurred ...

Comment: You have  misreading too many fundamentalist functional programmer blogs if you are talking about "Side effects" and suggesting that the standard RX way of building pipelines is wrong.

Comment: BTW have a look at the Observable.Create method.

Comment: To be totally clear. Anything that has a ``Subscribe`` method should be an IObservable. Understand that and your problem goes away.